# How to customize watch window formatting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I have a class something like:

```
class TimeSpan
{
  ...
private:
  __int64 m_ticks;
};
```

When debugging in VS, `TimeSpan` variables show up as unreadable huge numbers, and I need to use some kind of utility to make it readable. I would like to be able to see `TimeSpan` variables in a sensible way in the watch window, like "01:12:43.0000".

Is there a way to do this? How?

Comment: Yes, there is - you must change a certain XML file, AFAIK, but I don't know the details, so let's wait for an actual answer

Comment: Search for autoexp.dat and articles about it.  Another good keyword is "visualizer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find information about this [here](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120).
It also applies to VS2008. It is a bit underground and unstable. Take care !

Another option is to modify your class to include the formatted string and update it in all your non-const method.

```
class TimeSpan
{
  ... 
private:
  __int64 m_ticks;
#ifdef _DEBUG
  std::string m_str;
#endif
}
```